# How to present fixed effects in a linear mixed effects model for a journal?

Tags: mixed-model, references

When reporting the output for fixed effects in a linear mixed effects model for a journal publication, should I 
(1) include the coefficient estimates and p-values for the fixed effects
(2) a Type III ANOVA Table for the fixed effects
(3) both

I understand this depends on the journal but what is your preference? Thanks!

Comment: See what has been presented in a paper you thought it was well-presented and clear; emulate that. That said, this is an opinion-based question so I did vote to close it, sorry! Remember that your paper reflects *your* presentation of results on a matter. I personally like to provide bootstrapped CIs along with their KDE to visualise the variability directly but that's my take on how I want my results to be presented. ;) (Welcome to the community!)